# How to resolve: DateAdd results into an out-of-range value for DATETIME?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm basically calculating the difference between two dates in the format days:hours:mins:sec

```
CONVERT(varchar, datediff (s, [CreatedDate], [ClosedDate]) / (60 * 60 * 24)) + ':' + CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(s, datediff (s, [CreatedDate], [ClosedDate]), CONVERT(datetime2, '0001-01-01')), 108) AS Length
```

The above works when CreatedDate and ClosedDate are in DATETIME2.

But gives me this error when they are in DATETIME:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

```
CONVERT(varchar, datediff (s, [CreatedDate], [ClosedDate]) / (60 * 60 * 24)) + ':' + CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(s, datediff (s, [CreatedDate], [ClosedDate]), CONVERT(datetime, '0001-01-01')), 108) AS Length
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: well, `datetime` doesn't start with `0001-01-01`, you'll need `datetime2`

Comment: Also, beware declaring [`varchar` without length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx), and please [just type out `second`](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx).

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to get the seconds between the dates so the interval" is actually a datetime from time zero:

```
dateadd(second, datediff(second, [CreatedDate], [ClosedDate]), 0)
```

Then convert this to a format of "dd hh:mi:ss":

```
right(convert(varchar(255),
              dateadd(second, datediff(second, [CreatedDate], [ClosedDate]), 0)
              120), 11)
```

In SQL Server 2012+, you can use `format()`.

Comment: This is totally working! Side qs: How do I represent it in the format 2:04:23:02?

Comment: @90abyss . . . Use `replace()` or `stuff()` on the output.